# Is there a way to set a maximum area on a random rectangle in Paper.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I'm trying to place a randomly sized rectangle in the center of 1200x1200 canvas, with a min size of 200x200 and a max size of 900x900. However, I would also like to set a maximum area (of half the 900x900 maximum space) on the rectangle to prevent it from ever being one giant square. Basically, I want to create large random rectangles, or squares of a similar area, but never huge squares. I have the random rectangle part working, but not sure on how to limit the overall area.

```
var maxSize = new Size(700, 700);              // max size of 900x900 when combined with +200 below
var randomSize = Size.random();                // random number between 0 and 1
var size = (maxSize * randomSize) + 200;       // effectively creates a 200x200 minimum size, max 900x400

var box = new Rectangle(new Point(0,0), size); // creates rectangle at 0,0 with size
box.center = (600, 600);                       // centers rectangle at 600,600
var path = new Path.Rectangle(box);            // draws rectangle on screen
    path.fillColor = '#cccccc';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two constraints, your max size and area...
I'm assuming that we need to meet both, we will need to get the minimum between those

The area of a rectangle is equal to the product of its length and width
With a given area we can get a max side as a square of the area = `Math.sqrt(max_area)`

Integrating that to your code:

```
  const max_area = 788544
  var max_side = Math.sqrt(max_area) - 200
  var maxSize = new Size(Math.min(700, max_side), Math.min(700, max_side));
  ...
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction, but limiting the side length based on square root up front prevents any long or tall rectangles from being formed. I wonder if there's a way to randomize the height and width within the original max, but then check height against the (max_area/width) and take the minimum of that?

Comment: @MattEverson glad this send you on the right direction, quite often a small push like that is all we need

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer above, I ended up generating random width and height, then  checking the height against a max_height extrapolated from area and width. There's probably a way to streamline it, but it seems to work okay. Thank you!

```js
// Get random integer between two values, inclusive
function getRandomLength(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var max_area = 260000;
var width = getRandomLength(200,900);
var random_height = getRandomLength(200,900);
var max_height = max_area / width;
var height = Math.min(random_height, max_height);

var size = new Size(width, height);

var box = new Rectangle(new Point(0,0), size); 
box.center = (600, 600); // centers rectangle at 600,600
var boxPath = new Path.Rectangle(box);
boxPath.fillColor = '#cccccc';
```